# dialog.dismiss won't work.bugged?

Tags: android

I have the following code.It shows a dialog with a textview and some buttons.When a button is pressed,the dialog should close.But it doesn't.Is it bugged ? I tried both dialog.dismiss and dialog.cancel but it just won't work.

What's the solution ?

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Gestionarez.this);

            final TextView Dtv = new TextView(Gestionarez.this);
                 printeaza=new Button(Gestionarez.this);
                 stergere=new Button(Gestionarez.this);
                 trimitere=new Button(Gestionarez.this);
            final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();

            trimitere.setText("Trimite");
            trimitere.setTextSize(10);
            trimitere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            printeaza.setText("Printeaza");
            printeaza.setTextSize(10);
            printeaza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            stergere.setText("Sterge");
            stergere.setTextSize(10);
            stergere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    boolean deleted = file.delete();

                    Toast.makeText(Gestionarez.this, str+ " a fost sters ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    lv2.invalidateViews();


                }
            });
            LinearLayout ldialog = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);
            LinearLayout ldialogb = new LinearLayout(Gestionarez.this);
            ldialog.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ldialogb.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            Dtv.setText(text);
            ldialog.addView(Dtv);
            ldialogb.addView(trimitere);
            ldialogb.addView(printeaza);
            ldialogb.addView(stergere);
            ldialog.addView(ldialogb);
            ldialogb.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            Dtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
            Dtv.setPadding(60, 60, 60, 60);
            alert.setView(ldialog);

            alert.show();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you not remove those two lines? I thought dialogs by default close when a button is pressed

Comment: I need to remove the standard buttons.The buttons i'm talking about are buttons that i've added,usual buttons,as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are showing, a new created dialog which reference you dont hold in

```
alert.setView(ldialog);
alert.show();
```

And you are trying to dismiss a dialog which reference is different from that one:

```
 dialog.dismiss();
 dialog.cancel();
```

Remove the final from the dialog and change the last line "`alert.show();`" for

```
    dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.show();
```

And now you have a reference of that dialog, and it will work....

Comment: Still doesn't work.Now if i try and add dialog.dismiss(); it says the dialog needs tobe final.if i make it final the other says to remove the final

Comment: ok, you have a problem with logic here, instead of declaring that AlerDialog within a method, take it out as a class member, that will fix the issue...

Answer (score 0):

try `dialog.finsh();` then `dialog.dismiss();`

or this onClick :

```
if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
```